# What is the difference between Siebel AOM and Siebel Server Component?

Tags: object, siebel

What is the difference between Siebel AOM and Siebel Server Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic difference is that Siebel AOM (***Application Object Manager***) itself is a Siebel Server Component.
Siebel has several Server Components like AOM, BatchSync, JMS Component, Enterprise Application Integration component group, Workflow Process Manager etc....
However Admin can create Multiple Application Object Manager components which run in multithreaded mode. AOM handles the interaction between the web server and sends the requests to Siebel Server, thus it can handle multiple cocurrent users and fires requests on their behalf to the Siebel Server. Siebel Application Object Manager components host the Business Objects layer and Data Objects layer of the Siebel architecture.

Answer (score 0):

AOM is itself a Siebel Component. What makes an AOM different from other server components is that AOM is used for establishing user sessions i.e. they help end users to interact with the application through a UI.

Siebel Components basically has 3 modes in which they run :

1. Background Mode - A background component is defied as a constantly running process which performs tasks that require regular attention. e.g. "EAI receivers"
2. Batch components are typically invoked by an administrator, an end-user initiated workflow, or by schedule. Each task for these components has a defined start time and only consumes CPU and memory of the host machine when it is active. Once the task is complete, the operating system process is finished as well. e.g. "dbxtract" component
3. Interactive Mode - 
   Application object managers (AOM) are the dominant example for interactive components. Their main purpose is to wait for incoming requests from either the end users or external systems and handle the request according to the metadata information in the Siebel repository fie (.srf)